# How do I apply hook modifier to shape keys?

Tags: animation, mesh, shape-keys

Ok, so I figured out how to make my eyelashes for my character to follow the eyelids using the hook modifier. I'm somewhat stuck with applying the deformation as a shape key. For example, when I select the eyelash, the eyelid deforms along with it in object mode. However, I cannot apply it as a shape key in edit mode when selecting the eyelash itself, as the eyelid would not deform along with it. But in object mode it does. Does anyone have a workaround? It's my first time using shape keys.

Comment: "However, I cannot apply it as a shape key in edit mode when selecting the eyelash itself, as the eyelid would not deform along with it. But in object mode it does. Does anyone have a workaround?"  What's wrong with applying it in object mode?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I’ll try it again. Like when I move the eyelash, the eyelid gets deformed as expected, and if I apply as a shape key, it works, but the eyelash is not registered as a shape key. I’ll post a gif I suppose. Might be easier to explain.

Comment: So I’ll have to like go into edit mode and move the position of the eyelash to the same position as how the hook modifier is affecting the eyelid of the main mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Used a combination of bones and weight painting and the hook modifier to make the eyelash follow the eyelid. More idiot proof way is to just join the eyelash to the main body mesh via different vertex groups and go to edit mode to create the shape key as usual